# Adding firebase storage as dependency crashes the app

Tags: java, firebase-storage

I'm adding Firebase Storage to upload images for my app, however after adding the dependency; I get the following errors:

My build.gradle(app) looks like this.

It is sadly not possible for me to use a higher SDK version as its a school project and we are limited to SDK 19...

Tried some multidex but couldn't make it work...

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.socker"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    def nav_version = "2.1.0"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
```

....\Socker\app\src\main\java\com\project\socker\MainActivity.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

OR

Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 65924 > 65536)

Comment: I tried running it on 22 SDK, and it works, any suggestions for SDK 19?

Answer (score 0):

Used a lower version like 
        implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'